# treeView in python whit qt, scroll in one column

Tags: python, qt, scroll, treeview, qtreeview

I have a treeView done in python + qt, I need to know how to give scroll to a single column of this, in my case the first, as the content it has is larger than the width of the column and I do not want the column to be wider, the solution is just putting a scroll for that column but do not know how to put it, I've tried several ways but does not leave me, I need help

Comment: Can you post those trials?

Comment: my code is in [link]https://github.com/onlyOneUci/OnlyOne

Comment: any recommendation regarding the application is accepted

Comment: Per column-scrollbars aren't possible, you could only word-wrap the text over multiple lines, or shorten it.